# Custom validator for a phone number in JSF

Tags: java, regex, validation, jsf

i am trying to do some validation on a phone number although i understand how to do validation for just numbers of a set size this task is a little tricky

i am required to have validation on a users phone number however it must be  in any one of the formats illustrated below (where spaces are not significant):

```
+44 (23) 92846438
(023) 92846438
```

how would i create a custom validation that would validate against all combinations of the above phone numbers ?

Thanks

i have tried created a backing bean and validating through that

```
public class PhoneValidator implements Validator{

private static final String phone_PATTERN = "^[0-9-]{12,15}$";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    public UserNameValidator(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(phone_PATTERN);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(value.toString());
        if(!matcher.matches()){

            FacesMessage msg = 
                new FacesMessage("Phone validation failed", 
                        "Invalid phone number.");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);

        }

    }
}
```

would something like this work :

```
private static final String phone_PATTERN = "^[+][44][(0-9)][0-9-]{12,15}$";
```

and if so how can i get it to check both methods

edit, i have tried the above but it does not work, i think i am on the right lines here just can not get the combination right

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: added above, i can get the + and the length right etc but not the format

Comment: If you tried that, you could say what's exactly failing with that pattern. `Does not work` is not an specific explanation about your issue. You basically need to get the value match one of the two patterns and only if that doesn't happen throw the exception.

Comment: ok thanks, and how could i see where it is failing ? sorry i am new, the only reason i know it is failing is becuase the user gets an ajax message saying it has failed and will not let the user submit the values

Comment: A pattern evaluation tells you only if the pattern matches the provided string. You should try starting from a very basic case and match more complex cases till you get what you want. You'll find [this guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\\+\\d\\d )?\\(\\d{2,3}\\) \\d{8}$
```

The above matches both of those examples. Test out regex real quick and easy @ [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com)

- ^ matches the start of a string
- $ matches the end of a string
- \ java requires a double escape (for \d, ( etc.)
- \d matches any single number (0-9)
- {X} means the preceding pattern chunk must occur X times, {X,Y} also works if you're flexible
- also consider using "|" (pipe character) which stands for "or". Ex: in X|Y It will grab matches of X or Y.

Answer (score 0):

managed to find the regular expression needed

incase anyone needs it it is here, it will work on any u.k. number

```
private static final String Phone_PATTERN = "^\\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?|\\+)44\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?(?:0\\)?[\\s-]?\\(?)?|0)(?:\\d{2}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4}[\\s-]?\\d{4}|\\d{3}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3,4}|\\d{4}\\)?[\\s-]?(?:\\d{5}|\\d{3}[\\s-]?\\d{3})|\\d{5}\\)?[\\s-]?\\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\\s-]?11[\\s-]?11|45[\\s-]?46[\\s-]?4\\d))(?:(?:[\\s-]?(?:x|ext\\.?\\s?|\\#)\\d+)?)$";
```